# Storing timestamps with timezone in database rails 3.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, oracle

I have set my timezone as EDT in application.rb

```
config.time_zone = 'Eastern Time (US & Canada)'
config.active_record.default_timezone = :local
```

When I save the data to database(Oracle), it is getting stored in UTC format. But I need to store it in EDT. Is it possible? If so, how can I do it?

```
1.9.3-p545 :001 > Time.now
=> 2014-06-30 19:53:06 +0530 
1.9.3-p545 :002 > Time.now.in_time_zone
=> Mon, 30 Jun 2014 10:23:12 EDT -04:00
```

Comment: here is a blog post I wrote on rails timezones: http://jessehouse.com/blog/2013/11/15/working-with-timezones-and-ruby-on-rails/ - I do NOT recommend changing either `config.time_zone` or `config.active_record.default_timezone` - store everything in UTC and format/offset as needed when pulling data out of the database

Comment: @house9: My database server is in different timezone. (Say, EDT) - So, my requirement is such that I want to store the data also in EDT as other tables store that way while inserting a record.